# benefit `for of C loop form` than `traditional form`

Tags: bash

The tutorial I follow introduce `for: Traditional Shell Form` and `for: C from`

```
    $ for num in {1..3}; do echo "test"; done
    test
    test
    test
```

Additionally, Recent versions of bash have added a second form of for command syntax, one that resembles the form found in the C programming language.

```
    $ for (( num=0; num<3; num=num+1 ));do echo "test"; done
    test
    test
    test
```

I find the traditional form in python which does not support the C form

```
    In [1]: for i in range(3):
       ...:     print('test')
       ...:     
    test
    test
    test
```

I did not learn C,
What's benefit `C form` than `traditional form` in bash script?

Comment: If your definition of "recent" is close to *Two Decades Ago*, then yes, the C-style for loop is recent. (it came from ksh88 (as in 1988))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One advantage of the C form: you can efficiently use variables in your range definition. In the traditional form, you cannot do so efficiently. (Where I define "efficient" as "not requiring a sub-shell".) Consider:

```
begin=13
end=17
for (( num=$begin; $num < $end; num=$num+1 )); do
    echo $num
done

# invalid syntax, sadly
for num in {$begin..$end}; do echo $num; done

# instead have to use a sub-shell, not as efficient
for num in $(seq $begin $end); do
    echo $num
done
```